# Logistic Regression applied to biased dataset

Tags: logistic, classification, linear-model, calibration, labeling

I have collected a binary classification dataset in a somewhat biased way:

- I have thousands of unlabeled samples.
- A small percentage of these samples belong to the positive class.
- I know for a fact that my regressors are strongly correlated with the target.
- Using this fact I can collect positive samples by picking samples whose regressors are in the top end of the values.
- This way I can collect enough positive samples, and randomly pick the rest to get negative samples.
- I don't have the luxury to label many samples, yet I need enough positive samples to get an ok model.

However, I dont know the *true* percentage of positive samples. When fitting a logistic regression afterwards, I notice that my output is not very well calibrated (i.e. I need to tune the threshold to output a positive classification), probably because I collected the dataset in such a biased way.

I suspect that if I weighed my labeled samples using a density estimate of the regressors on the whole data this could have some sort of "importance sampling" effect, but I am not sure.

What can I do to improve model calibration?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. How does your procedure differ from just arbitrary classifying everything that is strongly correlated with the features as a positive class?

Comment: I still need to set some kind of threshold for them I guess, and I want to combine multiple regressors into a single, hopefully, calibrated score. I don't know if I would call my labeled data garbage - the problem is that it over-represents the positive class. But I don't know by how much.

Comment: I realize my question is very similar to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137893/using-unlabaled-data-in-a-classification-problem-there-is-labeled-data-but-it-c

Comment: With a tremendous effort you could solve for the optimum sampling strategy that would allow you to estimate a model given the amount of $ you have to spend don labeling.  This would involve a well-defined sampling scheme that would allow for recalibration of the intercept in the model.  It's not for the faint of heart.

Comment: I don't say this lightly but this seems like a decent application to try [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning). It is the "next step" after PU learning (which is related to your issue as you correctly recognised). Also, are you able to label at least "some" negative examples? Just to you can have an anchor from that side too?

Comment: @FrankHarrell do you mean similar to an [active learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)) approach? I have tried it in the past but it was a logistical nightmare... (Maybe I was too inexperienced though.) Being somewhat risk-averse: Without a reasonable infrastructure to implement that "optimal design strategy", I think doing some basic stratified random sampling might be good enough and steer us away from pitfalls of inadvertently biasing our sample.

Comment: Thanks for the comments,

@usεr11852 Yeah I can label negative samples easily. I actually did a kind of stratified sampling based on the regressors to ensure I "covered the ground", in addition to labelling samples for which the regressors were in the top values. I'll see if any specific semi-supervised learning approaches are applicable.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Its not that I have $ to do labelling, I do it myself :) But could you expand a bit ? Sampling based on model predictions to optimize the calibration or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to make this work is to have a well-defined set of probabilities. At the simplest level, you have 'high-yield' observations with values of the regressors where you expect a positive result, and 'low-yield' observations where you don't.   If you sample randomly from high-yield observations with probability $p_H$ (which could even be $p_H=1$) and randomly from low-yield observations with probability $p_L\ll p_H$, you'll get a sample that's enriched with positive outcomes.  A weighted regression using $1/p_L$ as sampling weights for the low-yield observations and $1/p_H$ as sampling weights for the high-yield observations will reconstruct the true population relationships.  You can have more complicated setups where there are more than two groups: all you need is that the probabilities really are the sampling probabilities you use, and that the probability is non-zero for every individual in the population.  Oversampling higher-yield individuals is a standard design approach in survey sampling.

If your sampling depends only on regressors that are actually in the model, and your model is correctly specified, you don't even need the weights, because whether or not an observation is in the sample is independent of the outcome conditional on the regressors. That's quite a strong set of assumptions, though.

Comment: Thomas I seem to recall an older paper by Anderson who showed how to adjust the intercept without using weights in the analysis, as an alternative.  Sorry I don't have the reference.

Comment: I actually attempted to do something like this with density estimation (kernel density estimation) of the regressors but did not seem to work in a toy experiment I created. But I will try your suggested approach it seems simpler and more principled.

Comment: Giving it more thought, the difference between what I tried (weighing my samples by an estimated p(x)) and what you are suggesting is that I did NOT sample the x's to be labeled according to 1/p(x).